# Scss child styling not applied

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I can't figure out why my .notes-list__item__contents isn't getting a white color on .note-list__item:hover... What am I doing wrong with my selector? I couldn't find similar case in the docs.

```css
.notes-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    &__item {
        padding: 30px;
        background-color: $secondary-color;
        border-radius: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;

        &:hover {
            background-color: $accent-color;
            color: #fff;

            &__contents { color: #fff; }
        }

        &__title {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

        &__contents {
            margin-top: 20px;
            color: $text-color;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<li className="notes-list__item">
    <div className="notes-list__item__title">Title</div>
    <div className="notes-list__item__contents">
      Some contents
    </div>
</li>
```

Having this doesn't feel quite scss

```
&:hover {
    .notes-list__item__contents { color: #fff; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i checked your output css and its resulting in below css

```
.notes-list__item:hover__contents {
   color: #fff;
}
```

As you can see its suffixing contents after the hover pseudo element.

you have to write like this in case of nested hover

```
&:hover &{
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;

    &__contents { color: #fff; }
}
```

This will generate below CSS

```
 .notes-list__item:hover .notes-list__item__contents {
     color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I have tried my best to avoid this. As I said; it doesn't feel quite scss.

Comment: Updated my answer please check if it works for you now.